# Trouble with editorial manager

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted a paper to a math journal last week.
The manuscript was sent back to me 3 times because of the following reasons:

- the order of the authors do not match in the manuscript as in the submission step (one time)
- there is no item stating the name of the data repository that I used to associate data (two times)

But the order of the authors was consistent and there is no associated data in the paper. I checked several times that I did not make a mistake in the submission steps. There might be a bug in the journal web page.

I explained this situation in the reply, but the editorial manager does not seem to take it seriously. I just received typical emails that seem to be automatically generated.

What should I do in this case? Should I withdraw and submit to another journal?

Comment: It depends on how strong your preference for this journal is. I would consider two escalation steps: 1. An email to the journal manager that you have a technical issue with the editorial system and need assistance with the submission process. If that doesn't work: 2. A similar email to the EiC. Of course, make sure that this journal doesn't require associated data (seems weird for a maths journal but who knows). If your preference for the journal isn't strong, take your manuscript elsewhere. However, that can be a significant amount of work if the style guide etc. are different.

Comment: When I had a technical issue with an editorial system (as a reviewer), I used their dedicated procedure to report technical issues (there was a contact form) and was contacted by the journals IT team. They didn't fix the issue but they helped me circumvent it (I had to switch off my ad blocker). Look for such a contact form or a "Report technical issues" button.